# Is there a good concrete reason to use IEntityTypeConfiguration over a Fluent config

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API that uses EF Core 6. We have upgraded the project a few times. Some of my older POCO models have annotations in the model, some I have a vanilla POCO class with only Fluent configs in `OnModelCreating`.

For the past month or so I have been migrating things to their own `IEntityTypeConfiguration` class. For me, this is a personal choice.

Other than a personal choice and to keep my `DbContext` tidy, is there a good concrete reason to use `IEntityTypeConfiguration` over a Fluent config?

As a side note, I do use `Optimize DbContext` and it doesn't seem to care one way or the other, the compiled models are the same.

Comment: Isn't fluent config is used inside the `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separation of concerns. You can configure every entity fluently in `OnModelCreating` without issue. That is, until your application grows and  you find that `OnModelCreating` all of a sudden contains a thousand lines of code and things start appearing out of order. Then it's time to start separating things out in order to keep your sanity.

The `IEntityTypeConfiguration` interface provides a means of doing that without having to implement the logic yourself. The configuration for each entity can be separated out into its own self-contained unit, and they can all be applied autimatically if you call `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` in `OnModelCreating`.

It's a similar concept to the `Startup` class from before .NET 6, which handled configuration of services for dependency injection and the request pipeline/middleware. It's all done at the time of application startup, but there's no reason everything has to happen in the same unit of code.

The starter templates for .NET 6 now puts all of that inside `Program.cs` using top level statements, which is fine for small applications, but eventually you're going to need something akin to the `Startup` class to prevent `Program.cs` from becoming bloated.